# How to shorten code by println(i for i in 1..10) like Python in Kotlin

Tags: iterator, kotlin

I'm studying Kotlin now.

When I read the Kotlin docs, It writes that I have `ranges` technique (Ex: 1..10) like Python. However, I try this code below but fail.

```
>>> print(i for i in 1..10)
...
error: expecting ')'
print(i for i in 1..10)
        ^
error: unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)
print(i for i in 1..10)
                    ^
```

Have any way to shorten this code by using `i for i in 1..10` like Python.

Comment: `for (i in 1..10) print(i)`

Comment: Thank @Magnus for this suggestion. I used it in Java, too. However, I wonder that have any way else to do that like an idiom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is not valid in Kotlin. You can use the `forEach` function  instead:

```
(1..10).forEach(::println)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.